# Looping of the files based on the keyword

Tags: bash, file, loops

I have a folder with the files. The name of each of the file can be divided on three parts: name - the same for all files; key - some keyword according to which the files can be grouped in 3 groups; the end number (1..10) - the position within the group. Example:

- the first group of files, defined by "key 1"

  ```
  name_key1_1
  name_key1_2
  name_key1_3
  ..
  name_key1_10
  ```
- the second group of files, defined by "key 2"

  ```
  name_key2_1
  name_key2_2
  name_key2_3
  ..
  name_key2_10
  ```
- the third group of files, defined by "key 3"

  ```
  name_key3_1
  name_key3_2
  name_key3_3
  ..
  name_key3_10
  ```

Now I need to loop all of the files with the aim to pass them to some program which combined the files from the same group (key). Each time I need to pass the files only with the same key in order to combined them together (avoiding mixing with the files with other keys during each processing). Thus having 3 groups of files, three combined files should be created using:

```
for file in ${input}/*.xtc; do
 file_name=$(basename "$file")
 prog  -f ${input}/${name}_${key}_* -o ${output}/${name}_${key}_combined.xtc -cat
done
```

In this example via the execution of prog I need to combine 10 files from each of the group (with the same key) avoiding mixing with the files from another group.

I will be grateful for an example of the realization of this workflow and its application of the filter e.g based on number of automatically detected groups taken from the name of the files.

Comment: The `<h1>` titles are hurting my eyes :(

Comment: Then [edit], that's how Stack Overflow works!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code, assuming the ${name} does not change while you loop.

/Edit:
As @tripleee is right we should use find instead of ls

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/tmp/test/"
output="/tmp/"
name="foo"
for key in $(find ${input} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" | rev| cut -d"_" -f2 | rev | sort | uniq ); do 
    for file in $(find ${input} -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name \*_${key}_\* -print | sort ); do
        prog  -f ${file} -o ${output}/${name}_${key}_combined.xtc -cat
    done
done
```

1. Find all files in the input directory.
2. Extract the penultimate field from the filename (a.k.a. the keyword);
3. Sort all keywords and print them only once.
4. For each keyword find the files containing that keyword.
5. Pass that file to your prog.
6. Done.

Comment: @tripleee you are right.  I've edited the script to meet your suggestion.

Comment: If it's a single directory then `printf '%s\n' "$input"/* | cut -d_ -f2` is sufficient. The `cut` removes the directory anyway and you can avoid both `find` and `sort` in the inner loop. But I'm not particularly convinced that this is what the OP wants; the question is unclear.

Comment: that is a good idea to split the fields by the underscores, but I just found that there are several underscores also within the names e.g AT1R_ss_charmm_tension_NPT_parinel_long_1.0bar_2.xtc                           here AT1R_ss_charmm_tension_NPT_parinel_long is the name                            l1.0bar is the keyword and _2 in the number of file with this keyword

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to uplate it with a more realistic requirement?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The keyword is now found by searching for the penultimate field  while splitting the files by underscore.

Answer (score 0):

If the fields are separated by underscores and there are no additional underscores in the values (i.e. all the file names contain exactly two underscores) then just split on underscore.

```
for file in ${input}/*.xtc; do
    oldIFS=$IFS
    IFS=_
    set -- ${file#"$input"/}
    IFS=$oldIFS
    dest="${output}/${1}_${2}_combined.xtc"
    test -e "$dest" && continue
    prog  -f "${input}/${1}_${2}_"{1..10} -o "$dest" -cat
done
```

The command `set -- string` splits `string` on the value of `$IFS` and populates the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, `$3` etc with the result. The parameter expansion `${variable#prefix}` returns the value of `$variable` with the `prefix` removed (if found).

We brutally loop over all the files, but skip `prog` if the output file already exists.

If you need to peel off underscores from the end, maybe something like this inside the loop:

```
     base=${file%_*}
     tail=${file#"$base"}
     head=${base%_"$tail"}
     dest="$outputdir/${head#$input/}_combined.txt"
     test -e "$dest" && continue
     :
```

where `${variable#suffix}` removes a suffix.

If you can redesign how your inputs are structured, so that the groups - and perhaps the names before them, too - are subdirectories instead, that would make it very natural and straightforward to process a set without any additional logic.

Comment: Notice, though, that 10 will sort before 2 in many locales. Can you change it so that the set is numbered from 0 through 9, or pad the single-digit ones with a leading zero? I fixed that with a brace expansion `{1..10}` but it's a bit of an eyesore.